# Запуск приложения с базой данных на другом комьютере

Tags: delphi

Как запустить приложение с БД MS SQL на другом компьютере, при отсоединения базы Adoconnection отключается, как его включить из приложения на другой системе, не залазия в код?

Answer (score 2):

[@Ник_qd](/users/20045/%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_qd) Итак, поправьте меня если я не прав, я так понимаю что: у вас есть приложение которое работает с БД MS SQL сервер на одном компьютере и вам нужно его запустить на другом компьютере, а БД будет на первом? Если так, то в вам приложении есть строка подключения к БД. Если она в файле конфигурации - то просто поменяйте в ней путь к базе с localhost (127.0.0.1 или как ещё она там у вас прописана) на имя вашего сервера в сети или его IP адрес но не локальный. Если строки в файле конфигурации нет, то её надо туда поместить. :-)